# Terminal showing different name

Tags: command-line

I went to open my terminal and it said this:

```
Gillians-iPhone:~ milo$
```

I know for a fact that this is not my computer name. I am running mac osx 10.13.4. I am on a public wifi network at a hotel. This just recently started happening. I set my laptop up as Milo’s MacBook Air.

[image: This is the image]

Comment: What output does the `hostname` command produce?

Comment: Gillians-iPhone. Thats it. Should be Milo's Mac Book Air or something like that.

Comment: Try: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/86545

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got the name of the hostname of the previous user by some DHCP behaviour.

I would not be surprised that after a while, depending on the Wifi setup, that your name comes back to normal.

Nonetheless, one strategy to minimize this, in the present, and in the (near) future, is to configure the DHCP service to (try to) for the hostname.

Go to System Preferences->NetWork->Wi-Fi->Advanced->TCP/IP, and fill the field "DHCP Client ID" with your hostname.

[image: System Preferences > Network > Advanced]